# How to open a view with Alarm?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uilocalnotification

With **UILocalNotification** when alarm is ringing at that time parallel i want to open a custom view.
I am using following code for the same.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notification == nil)
    return;
NSDate *dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
notification.fireDate = dt;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

notification.alertBody = @"After 10Secs...";
notification.alertAction = @"View";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

With this code only notification fires.

[image]

Comment: Please could you clarify. When you say a custom view. Do you mean the Notification being a custom view or when the notification is tapped a custom view will display from your app?

Comment: @Naughty_Ottsel Yes,with Notification being a custom view. Or if possible then if notification tapped a custom view opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now clarification has been set on what you are looking for.

Notifications cannot be custom views. They are handled by Apple and all look the same. The only change being the Application Name, Icon and Notification Body.

However, when you are scheduling the Notification you can store custom data in the UserInfo property of the notification.

Then when you receive the delegate call of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you can check the options dicitionary for your notification. Check the userInfo and display a viewController with your custom view in.

Apple has an extensive programming guide on [Notifications here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

Comment: How fetch the detail of dictionary? Can u give some code for the same?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW15

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];
        [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method
        app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
    }
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}